# Event to fire when an angular *ngIf statement evaluates in template

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-template

If I have the following:

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user" class="container">
   <p>{{user.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can execute code when the `div` above finally appears on screen?

Comment: Cant you Just subscribe in Code to the user$ observable?

Comment: What kind of code do you want to execute?

Comment: I want to hide my loader (spinner)! I hide/show it via a service that emits a boolean value using a `ReplaySubject`. The actual spinner component is placed at the app's root component with an `*ngIf` statement hooked to that boolean value.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `*ngIf` will remove that DOM element and all attached components/directives. So you can just write a simple directive that executes an event when it's first created. When the `*ngIf` transitions from *false* to *true* the directive will be created (again, and again, etc...)

```js
@Directive({selector: '[after-if]'})
export class AfterIfDirective implements AfterContentInit {
    @Output('after-if')
    public after: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
       // timeout helps prevent unexpected change errors
       setTimeout(()=> this.after.next());
    }
}
```

Sample HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user" (after-if)="your expression">
   <p>{{user.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

A solution **without the creation of a new directive** is to take advange of `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` behaviour:

> Property decorator that configures a view query. The change detector
> looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in
> the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the
> selector, the property is updated.

---

#### 1. ViewChild

The important part is ***If the view DOM changes*** wich means that in this case this'll only be triggered when the element is created or destroyed.

First declare a variable name for the element, for the sample i used `#userContent`

```html
<div #userContent *ngIf="user$ | async as user" class="container">
  <p>user.name</p>
</div>
```

Then add a `@ViewChild` reference inside your component:

```ts
@ViewChild('userContent') set userContent(element) {
  if (element) {
     // here you get access only when element is rendered (or destroyed)
  }
}
```

This solution was provided inside [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242993/1657465), also `@ViewChild` behaviour detail is available [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

---

#### 2. ViewChildren

Another solution without using a new directive is to subscribe to
`@ViewChildren` change observable, instead of using `@ViewChild` put it like this:

```ts
@ViewChildren('userContent')
private userContent: QueryList<any>;
```

And then subscribe to it change observable:

```ts
userContent.changes.pipe(takeUntil(this.$d)).subscribe((d: QueryList<any>) => {
  if (d.length) {
    // here you get access only when element is rendered
  }
});
```

I've preferred the `@ViewChildren` way because to me it was easier to handle observables than validations inside `setter's`, also this approach is closer to the "Event" concept.

---

#### 3. ngAfterViewInit()

**NOTE:** this option doesn't apply to OP question, as he's rendering a `div`, not a component.

As a general recommendation, when possible, avoid using any approach listed in this question. Instead, add an event triggered inside the `ngAfterViewInit` method of your child component. This is way more natural as Angular is intended to be used.

Child component:

```
// declare the event
@Output()
public created= new EventEmitter<any>();

// later on, trigger the event every time the component is rendered
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.created.next();
}
```

Parent component:

```html
<my-user-content-component #userContent (created)="onUserContentCreated($event)"></my-user-content-component>
```

```
@ViewChild('userContent')
userContent: MyUserContentComponent;

onUserContentCreated() {
    // here you get access only when element is rendered using `this.userContent`
}
```

---

**Note about Observables:**

All observables need to be unsubscribed, otherwise you'll provoke memory leaks; there's a lot of ways to prevent that, as a recommendation, my favorite way is the RxJs function `takeUntil`, this part: `pipe(takeUntil(this.$d))` and the following at your `ngOnDestroy` method:

```js
private $d = new Subject();
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$d.next();
    this.$d.complete();
}
```

The reason I recommend this way is because the amount of extra code to implement it is very low, also; **you can use the same variable for all of your subscriptions** in the component (`this.$d`). For more details/options about unsubscription approaches see [this other related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/1657465).

Comment: The subscribe function returns a subscription that you must store a reference to and unsubscribe to when the component is destroyed (e.g. in ngOnDestroy). Is there a way to make this less verbose?

Comment: There's a lot of ways @Ryan, my favorite is the RxJs function `takeUntil`, there's a lot more detail in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/1657465

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is something like the "custom ngSubscribe directive". IOW, something to manage registration and removal of the subscription (similar to the async pipe). The amount of boilerplate code for each subscription is undesirable. The code you have written above does not unsubscribe. When the component is destroyed, the subscription lives on. You can prove this by logging inside the subscription.

Comment: @RyanHaney, thank you for your feedback, I've just added the `unsubscribe` method for the sake of developers that might not know that all observables need to be unsubscribed

Comment: I just happened upon this interesting package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@w11k/ngx-componentdestroyed.

Comment: Looks the same than the `takeUntil` approach, but with the `ngOnDestroy` method inside the extended class