# How to get element after displaying it using *ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm facing this issue frequently. I have an element as shown

```html
<div class="element-1" *ngIf="isShown"></div>
```

by default, `isShown = false;` and by clicking an element, I'm making `isShown = true;`

Now, in the same click callback function If I try to get `element-1` as

`$('.element-1')`, I am not getting that element because it might not in the DOM immediately when the `isShown = true`.

I am able to get the same using `ngAfterContentChecked`. But `ngAfterContentChecked` called many times.

So, how can I get the element by not using `ngAfterContentChecked`?

### Edit

**This is my element**

```html
<app-card-kpi-inline-overlay #kpisOverlay class="child-component all-kpis-overlay-wrap {{selectedView}}" [style.left.px]="kpiLeft" *ngIf="data['openKpiDetails']==true" [cardData]="data"></app-card-kpi-inline-overlay>
```

**This is my ts method code**

```js
@ViewChild('kpisOverlay') kpisOverlay: ElementRef;

showKpiSection(i, event, card) {
    card['openKpiDetails'] = !card['openKpiDetails'];
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (card['openKpiDetails']) {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            const el: HTMLElement = this.kpisOverlay.nativeElement; 
            console.log(el); // always showing undefined
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

I am trying to toggle the flag. But the console always printing `undefined`.

Below is my toggle element

```html
<div (click)="showKpiSection(i, $event, data)">Get element</div>
```

Comment: Using jquery with angular is not usually recommended. Tell us what you are trying to do after selecting the element. Maybe there is a non-jquery way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want get an DOM element? Angular is built with data-binding. Get an div by Id or class via JQuery is not recommanded

Comment: I want to apply width dynamically after setting the flag to true.

Comment: I updated my question. Please go through it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event to fire when an angular \*ngIf statement evaluates in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472771/event-to-fire-when-an-angular-ngif-statement-evaluates-in-template)

Answer (score 7):

I will never say it enough :

> **Using JQuery with Angular is an anti-pattern. You should not touch the DOM yourself, you should let the framework do it for you**.

Now, in a full ANgular way :

```
<div #firstElement *ngIf="isShown"></div>
```

In your TS :

```
@ViewChild('firstElement') firstElement: ElementRef;
```

If you want the element, in your function, once the value of `isShown` is set to true, use this

```
const el: HTMLElement = this.firstElement.nativeElement;
```

If it doesn't work, trigger a change detection, because it means Angular hasn't finished detecting the changes yet.

**EDIT** Since your component is in a loop, you should use `@ViewChildren` instead.

I made a working **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ttpf8y?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)** for you, look at the code, it's basically the same principle, only that the element becomes an array of elements.

Comment: No, I am unable to get the element. Showing undefined. How can I trigger a change detection? What steps should I do to get the element and add width to it dynamically?

Comment: to trigger a change detection, the fastest is simply to use a time out with `setTimeout(() => {const el: HTMLElement = this.firstElement.nativeElement;})`. Once you get the element, simply do `el.style.width = el.offsetWidth + 30 + 'px'`

Comment: I updated my code. I am still getting undefined value

Comment: Because your condition is `*ngIf="data['openKpiDetails']==true"` but in your code, you never set it to true. This means your element never shows up, that's why you're getting undefined.

Comment: `card['openKpiDetails'] = !card['openKpiDetails'];` this statement toggling the variable. Please re check

Comment: `data` is different from `card`. If you use a function or an accessor, it would be good to know. Otherwise, those two are different variables.

Comment: Oh sorry. on click I am passing `data` and please consider that both are same

Comment: Ok then, what happens if you put a one second delay into your timeout ? Dos it work then ?

Comment: No, `this.kpisOverlay` is printing Component class with its properties. not as DOM element as it is a component itself. `this.kpisOverlay.nativeElement` is printing undefined.

Comment: Because `nativeElement` is the HTML element, `kpisOverlay` is an Angular object (ElementRef). If even a one second delay isn't working, then you have something wrong with your code, that doesn't allow your component to be displayed. is your component on your screen ? can you see it ?

Comment: Yes, it is showing but I just want to apply some styles dynamically. For that, I am accessing it. But I am unable to get it as DOM element

Comment: Then I will need to have a **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, because you either do something wrong you didn't share on SOF, or you have an unique issue that needs to be reported to the Angular team.

Comment: Wait ... is this element in a *ngFor ? @Mr_Perfect

Comment: Yes. It is there in a loop. And I tried moving the component into a wrapper as the reference not working on the component selector. Now, it is working but there is little jerk before setting the width in the timeout even I use `0` second delay in timeout

Comment: See, that's why you should post your whole code. **[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ttpf8y?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)** to show you the working code.

Comment: But there is no *ngIf right and why references not working on component selector?

Comment: Now there is ;) and could you rephrase your question ?

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` behaviour:

> Property decorator that configures a view query. The change detector
> looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in
> the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the
> selector, the property is updated.

As a general recommendation, **when possible**, prefer the 3rd approach over the others. As it is way more natural, as Angular is intended to be used.

---

#### 1. ViewChild approach using a `setter`

The important part is ***If the view DOM changes*** which means that in this case this'll only be triggered when the element is created or destroyed.

First declare a variable name for the element, for the sample i used `#element1`

```html
<div #element1 class="element-1" *ngIf="isShown"></div>
```

Then add a `@ViewChild` reference inside your component:

```ts
@ViewChild('element1') set element1(element) {
  if (element) {
     // here you get access only when element is rendered (or destroyed)
  }
}
```

---

#### 2. ViewChildren approach using Observables

Another solution is to subscribe to
`@ViewChildren` change observable, instead of using `@ViewChild` put it like this:

```ts
@ViewChildren('element1')
private element1: QueryList<any>;
```

And then subscribe to it change observable:

```ts
element1.changes.subscribe((d: QueryList<any>) => {
  if (d.length) {
    // here you get access only when element is rendered
  }
});
```

I've preferred the `ViewChildren` way because to me it was easier to handle observables than validations inside `setter's`, also this approach is closer to the "Event" concept.

---

#### 3. ngAfterViewInit() as a component event

Add an event triggered inside the `ngAfterViewInit` method of your child component (when possible, prefer this approach over the others).

Child component `app-card-kpi-inline-overlay`:

```
// declare the event
@Output()
public created= new EventEmitter<any>();

// later on, trigger the event every time the component is rendered
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.created.next(this);
}
```

Parent component:

```html
<app-card-kpi-inline-overlay #kpisOverlay (created)="onComponentCreated($event)"></app-card-kpi-inline-overlay>
```

```
onComponentCreated(elem: CardKpiInlineOverlayComponent) {
    // here you get access only when element is rendered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your element like this:

```
<div #element-1 class="element-1" *ngIf="isShown"></div>
```

And then access it with:

```
@ViewChild('element-1') element1;
```

in your Component.
The example on this page looks close to what you are trying to do:
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score -1):

For me, it works when I remove property `static` from `viewChild` decorator

```
@ViewChild('mainTextBox', {read: ElementRef, static: true}) public parentTextBoxElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

to

```
@ViewChild('mainTextBox', {read: ElementRef}) public parentTextBoxElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```