# event when div ngIf is rendered

Tags: angular, event-handling

I was looking at issue at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44737636/973651

I've a div with an `ngIf` condition, and I'd like to capture an event for when the `div` gets rendered. Supposedly, you can use the `AfterContentInit` event.
The article I cited above, shows an example, which I've replicated but no luck in getting it to work.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get this to work. I get no errors, but it doesn't work for me.

My directive is defined as:

```js
import { AfterContentInit, EventEmitter, Output, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[after-if]' })
export class AfterIfDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @Output('after-if')
  public after: EventEmitter<AfterIfDirective> = new EventEmitter();

  public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    debugger;
    setTimeout(() => {
      // timeout helps prevent unexpected change errors
      this.after.next(this);
    });
  }
}
```

In my page component I import.

```js
import { AfterIfDirective } from '../directives/after-if';


@NgModule({
  providers: [],
  imports: [NgModel, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClientModule, 
      AfterIfDirective],
  exports: [NgModel, BrowserAnimationsModule, AfterIfDirective]
})
```

and in the html:

```
<div *ngIf="chkTearline.checked; else NotTearline" (after-if)="Clicked()">
```

what am I missing?

Does this not work in Angular 5?

```js
  Clicked() {
    console.log('something got clicked');
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your code with the Clicked function? Also drop in a console log in the `setTimeout` to see if it's firing in there.

Comment: here's the Clicked function.

Clicked() {
    console.log('something got clicked');
  }

Comment: why so strange selector name and input name ? whats wrong with default Angular style afterIf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event to fire when an angular \*ngIf statement evaluates in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472771/event-to-fire-when-an-angular-ngif-statement-evaluates-in-template)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `setter` like in example below:

template:

```html
<div #elementToCheck *ngIf="expr"></div>
```

component:

```js
@ViewChild('elementToCheck') set elementToCheck () {
  // here you get access only when element is rendered (or destroyed)
}
```